# Installing Ubuntu Server fails to detect NIC

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ethernet, nic

- O/S: Ubuntu 8.04 Server LTS 64-bit
- Motherboard: Supermicro x8ste
- NIC: dual onboard Intel 82574L

Installation fails, complaining that no Network Interface could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and compile the driver after installation:
http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/adapters/gigabit-ct/gigabit-ct-overview.htm

Comment: I ended up switching to Ubuntu 9.10 server, but this is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/513292, the Intel 82574L NIC will not be supported on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.